# SSIS 2014 Package Trim incoming column value

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am using the SSIS package to read the data from the flat file and then push the data to the SQL Server db. But some of the incoming columns are containing the blank spaces and i would like to trim them.

I am unable to understand how to perform this small task of column trimmming inside the data flow of the SSIS package.

Please suggest how to make this change.

SSIS Package version 2014

IDE :- VS.NET 2017

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `Derived column` transformation and proper combination of [LTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql) and [RTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql)

I am using `LTRIM(RTRIM([column]))`. This will remove trailing and leading spaces.

[image: img]

Comment: after making this change in the SSIS package under VS.NET 2015 and also 2017. I am getting the runtime error saying "The Script Task is corrupted. There were errors during task validation. "

Comment: LEN(TRIM(TaxID)) == 0 ? NULL(DT_WSTR,9) : TRIM(TaxID)

Comment: Please suggest any solution

Comment: How's that related to the question you've asked ?

Answer (score 1):

@Karan, Script Error:  This is actually another question, and has nothing to do with derived columns.  Script Tasks often get corrupted by the upgrade process and may dissappear entirely.  Just copy the script as it should be, and overwrite the script when needed.